# Flink sql dynamic partition filter

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, apache-iceberg

I have a simple flink (1.16 - apache icebeg tables )sql job that runs the following query

```sql
select * from <table> where date_partition >= ( select min(date_partition) from <table B> )
```

The job runs correctly but the entire table is scanned and the filter is only applied after the full table scan.

How can I force the planner/optimizer to resolve the sub-query first thus avoiding the full table scan ?